# Как повесить яндес цели на форму, если это wp тема astra, в сочетании с плагином elemetor pro?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, яндекс-метрика

**Как повесить яндес цели на форму**, если это wp тема astra, в сочетании с плагином elemetor pro, где формы это формы elementor?

Пытался вешать событие на кнопку, дебагер (`name-site/?_ym_debug=1`)  показывает что сработало, но в мертике не показывает, данный вариант ни то, ни другое.

Есть подозрение что сам код метрики блокируется где-то глубже. Ниже код, цели проверял несколько раз, id, к которым обращаюсь тоже.

Answer (score 0):

вариантов несколько: на форму или на кнопку, в твоём случае работает, но как я понял... сам плагин wordPress где то подавляет события яндекса. Но цель воткнуть код выполена:

```
    let button = document.getElementById('btn-call-back');
    let buttonSecond = document.getElementById('btn_border');
    button.setAttribute('onclick', "ym(XXXX, 'reachGoal', ' XXX'); return true;");
    buttonSecond.setAttribute('onclick', "ym(XXXX, 'reachGoal', ' XXXX'); return true;");
```

Comment: Не надо давать много ответов. Отредактируйте один ответ, второй удалите.

Answer (score 0):

Другой вариант вешать на саму форму:

```
    let form = document.querySelector('form');
    form.setAttribute('onclick', "ym(XXX, 'reachGoal', ' XXX'); return true;");
```